# Node 18 Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, openssl

Upgrading to Node v18 but when I start the app I am getting the error:

```
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/Users/user/src/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^
```

Have tried solutions from [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported). I've tried updating the webpack config (or in my case the `react-app-rewired` config) to include:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    config.output.hashFunction = 'xxhash64';
    return config;
  },
};
```

but that just leads to the error:

```
Error: Digest method not supported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
```

I also tried setting the hashFunction to `sha256` and `sha512` but they result in the original digital envelope error.

I also tried `npm audit --fix` but the error remains.

I am able to start the app if I prepend the run command in package.json with `NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' react-app-rewired start",
    ...
```

Is that the only solution to this?  Thanks.

Comment: It’s that or change your node/webpack versions.

Comment: Welp, i'm on the latest `react-scripts` and I imagine newer versions of Node would need this as well, since I believe the "cause" of the error was Node 17 closing a security hole in the SSL provider (according to the other ticket I linked to).