# No able to start the react server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I was making an ecommerce site, I made navigation bar and sign up button until then it was okay but when I tried to fetch the data present in my cloud DB (MongoDB Atlas) on the front end using `Redux` , The frontend went blank and Started throwing this error in the console :

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10) C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19 throw err;   ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\astha\projects\flipkart-clone\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],   library: 'digital envelope routines',   reason: 'unsupported',   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you are using an old module.  If you run `npm audit fix`, do you experience the same issue?

Comment: [This SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69692842/1409374) provides some insight.  The correct answer seems to depend on package/module verisons.

Comment: @rickg12hs  Yes , even after npm audit fix same issue

Comment: Did you try any other solutions in the answers of the above linked Q/A?  There are a lot of them!

Comment: @rickhg12hs  I had to reinstall every module again, Now it's working