# opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ], I get this error when running npm start in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
(C:\Users\Shashank\Documents\.vscode\webdevelopment\React from basic\keeper-app-part-1-starting\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\Shashank\Documents\.vscode\webdevelopment\React from basic\keeper-app-part-1-starting\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

This error comes when i am running npm start

I tried changing code and other references from internet but still same error!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)