# How can I set node-options properly in `.yarnrc`?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

### What I was trying

using yarn classic `yarn: '1.22.19'`

and wanted to use `--openssl-legacy-provider` node option for webpack

it's only recognised on after nodejs v17, I don't want to set NODE_OPTIONS env var somewhere else.

### How npm and .npmrc works

when I run (without `node-options` in .yarnrc)

```
npm config set "node-options=--openssl-legacy-provider" -g
```

my .npmrc has

```
node-options=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

but only works when I run `npm run build`.  (like `"build": "webpack"`)
and does not work with `yarn build`.

### How yarn and .yarnrc works

```
yarn config set node-options -- --openssl-legacy-provider
```

so my `~/.yarnrc` has

```
node-options "--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

but it does not work with `yarn build` command (like `"build": "webpack"`)

### What I think

`yarn config list` has

```
info npm config
{
  'node-options': '--openssl-legacy-provider'
}
```

so I guess `yarn config` should not be required fot what I already have in `.npmrc`

but yarn does not use that `node-options`

How can I set `node-options` properly for yarn?

---

p.s.

This question was to provide workaround for webpack initially.

because webpack<v5.54 has default hash function `md4`, but `new crypto.Hash('md4')` in node.js>16 errors with `error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

For addressing this, I think setting `output.hashFunction` is better solution like

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13572#issuecomment-923736472
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/4902709