# Problem with React Router: routes not working in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating a website for a restaurant, for my final Coursera project, and I have to create the reserve a table section. When settting react router, my page becomes blank. Before setting this part, the page renders perfectly.

***Here is my main code:***

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import BookingPage from './bookingPage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav />
      <Header />
      <Route path="/" exact component={BookingPage} />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***This is my bookingPage component:***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useCallback } from 'react';
import BookingForm from './BookingForm';

const availableTimesReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INITIALIZE_TIMES':
            return action.payload;
    case 'UPDATE_TIMES':
        return action.payload;
    default:
    return state;
    }
};
const BookingPage = () => {
  const [availableTimes, dispatchAvailableTimes] = useReducer(availableTimesReducer, []);
  const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState('');

  const fetchData = async (date) => {
    try {
      
      const response = await fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Meta-Front-End-Developer-PC/capstone/master/api.js?fecha=${date}`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Error en la solicitud');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Error al obtener datos de la API: ' + error.message);
    }
  };
  const initializeTimes = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const today = new Date();
      const formattedDate = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];
      const availableTimes = await fetchData(formattedDate);
      dispatchAvailableTimes({ type: 'INITIALIZE_TIMES', payload: availableTimes });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  }, [dispatchAvailableTimes]);
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeTimes(); 
    }, []);

    const updateTimes = async (selectedDate) => {
      try {
        const availableTimes = await fetchData(selectedDate);
        const additionalTimes = ["20:00", "20:30", "21:00"];
        const updateAvailableTimes = [...availableTimes, ...additionalTimes];
        dispatchAvailableTimes({ type: 'UPDATE_TIMES', payload: updateAvailableTimes });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating times:", error);
      }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
      initializeTimes();
    }, [initializeTimes]);

  return (
    <>
      <BookingForm
        availableTimes={availableTimes}
        selectedTime={selectedTime}
        setSelectedTime={setSelectedTime}
        updateTimes={updateTimes} />
  </>
  );
}

export default BookingPage;
```

***which imports bookingForm component:***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function BookingForm({ availableTimes, selectedTime, setSelectedTime, updateTimes }) {
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');
  const [numberOfGuests, setNumberOfGuests] = useState('');
  const [occassion, setOccassion] = useState('');

  const handleDataChange = (e) => {
    const newDate = e.target.value;
    setDate(newDate);
    updateTimes(newDate);
  }
   const handleSubmit= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Reservation submitted");
    console.log("Selected time:", selectedTime)
   }

  return (
    <div className="all-form">
      <div className="div-title">
        <h2 className="reservation-table">Reserve a table</h2>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
        <fieldset>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="date">Choose a date: </label>
            <input
              id="date"
              type="date"
              name="date"
              value={date}
              onChange={handleDataChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="time">Choose time: </label>
            <select
              id="time"
              value={selectedTime}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedTime(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value=""></option>
              {availableTimes.map((timeOption, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={timeOption}>
                  {timeOption}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="guests">Number of guests: </label>
            <input
              id="guests"
              type="number"
              name="guests"
              value={numberOfGuests}
              onChange={(e) => setNumberOfGuests(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="occassion">Occasion: </label>
            <input
              id="occasion"
              type="text"
              name="occasion"
              value={occassion}
              onChange={(e) => setOccassion(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div className="button-form">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookingForm;
```

***and finally here is the nav section:***

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Nav = () => {
return (
      <nav>
        <div className="navigation">
            <div className="img-logo">
                <img src="Image-2.png" alt="logo-little-lemon" width="200" height="60"/>
            </div>
            <div className="navigation-ul">
                <ul>
                        <li><Link to ="/home">Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/bookingPage">Reservations</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/orderonline">Order Online</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/Testimonials">Testimonials</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )}
    export default Nav;
```

***This is the package.json file***

```
{
  "name": "prueba-coursera-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

***the error that appears is:***

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\myuser\prueba-coursera-project\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: What version of react router you are using?

Comment: HI @Sarkar. I am using "^18.2.0"

Comment: @NachoEigu `^18.2.0` is the version of react. In this case - as Sarkar already asked - the version of react-router-dom is more interesting. For me it looks like you are using version `5.x.x`.

Comment: Hi @Palladium02 it's "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"

Comment: @NachoEigu none of them are react router, please update the question and show us a picture of all of the dependencies in you package.json

Comment: Hi @Sarkar. I have adapted my question and added the package.json file I use.

Comment: Looks like you have not installed (react-router-dom) run this in your terminal `npm i react-router-dom`

Comment: Thank you @Sarkar .I installed it and the package.json changed, but when I execute "npm start" appears other error that I attached in the question above.

Comment: That's another issue have nothing to do with react dom router   https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699772/13741787

Comment: Thank you @Sarkar. I will check that and maybe it could be the solution. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

> "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",

You specify React-Rotuer v6 (RRv6) as a project dependency but are using the React-Router v5 route syntax. In RRv6 the `Route` component hasn't any `exact` prop, all routes are now ***always*** exactly matched, and instead of `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, all are replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, e.g. JSX, value. All routes must be rendered directly within the `Routes` component. `Routes` is the replacement to the v5 `Switch` component and handles matching routes by path to the current URL.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes, // <-- import Routes
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav />
      <Header />
      <Routes> // <-- render Routes parent
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<BookingPage />} // <-- element prop with JSX
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```