# I am trying to deploy react project in vercel but getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, tailwind-css

[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PDFV.png)

my package.json code is:

```
{
    "name": "react-tailwind-starter",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
        "@react-oauth/google": "^0.11.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "axios": "^0.22.0",
        "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "nanoid": "^3.1.28",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.2.0",
        "swiper": "6.0.2",
        "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.0.3",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "craco start",
        "build": "craco build",
        "test": "craco test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^9",
        "postcss": "^7",
        "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
    }
}
```

I tried multiple time but unable to fix this issue.

Comment: There already many similar question being asked, take a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported In short, the Node version 18 might be a problem for your react and react-scripts version.