# Can't execute angular project

Tags: node.js, angular

https://github.com/swordEdge/deed-angular-solidity

While I was trying to run a dev server for this angular project, I encountered the following error.

```
$ ng serve
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
...
Compiling jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2 : es2015 as esm2015
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active(node:8340) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
10% building 3/4 modules 1 active E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:68  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
    at processResource (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at runLoaders (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
    at NormalModule.build (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at E:\Projects\deed-angular\deed-angular-solidity\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.9.0
```

For Node.js and Angular CLI, I use the following versions.

```
$ ng v
 
Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 20.9.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

When I changed the Node.js version to 12.x or 16.x, it says

```
Node.js version v12.11.1 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

If anyone has encountered the same error before, please let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported ?