# React project crashing on running "npm start"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

My development server was running successfully till I fixed some warnings with `npm fix audit`   and now the development server as refused to run with this error message showing

```
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\mern-project\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],      
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.8.1
```

I tried using `npm fix audit --force` but it seems that only worsen the situation

Below is the `package.json` as requested

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the package.json?

Comment: Not sure that link was correct.  Read the entirety of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: @SunnyParekh I have added the package.json on the question