# This error is encountered while running the script npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, runtime-error, npm-scripts, npm-package

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\AFileManager\Project\Online-E-learning-Website\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

This is the error what I encountered while running the script of npm start. Please look into the error and suggest some changes and solution

Comment: This is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported