# I have installed npm install react-scroll for adding scrolling to my nav items ? Version Issue occured

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have installed react-scroll library to provide smooth scrolling when clicking on the navigation items. But faced version issue on it. Then I run the following commands

1.npm audit fix --force
2.npm install -g npm@10.4.0

I have terminated the localhost and re-run again, after that  the blank page was opened on the browser and showing error message on my terminal like below.

please help me to resolve this issue.

error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at handleParseError (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
at Array. (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
at Storage.finished (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
PS C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio>

Answer (score 0):

From your log:

> (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\myRepo\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash

**webpack** by default uses "**md4**" as the default arg when calling createHash.

Ever since Node **v17**, **md4** was no longer an option from **crypto** package(internal/crypto/hash).

From your log, you are using Node.js **v18.17.1** hence the issue, you can also reproduce the above issue by executing a simple node program like:

```
node -p "require('node:crypto').createHash('md4')"
```

Now it's not a recommended solution but if you are only playing around(not a production thing), you can set below env, before retrying:

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

In PowerShell this would be:

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

A more correct solution is to configure webpack to use other hashing functions, like sha256, xxhash64... here's some resources in case you want to dig deeper:

- [Reddit - Node 17 currently breaks most Webpack](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/qd14bm/node_17_currently_breaks_most_webpack/)
- [Webpack Hashed Module IDs Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hashed-module-ids-plugin/)
- [Angular CLI GitHub Issue #1656](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656)
- [Stack Overflow - Error Message: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)
- [Node.js Blog - OpenSSL November 2022 Vulnerability](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/openssl-november-2022)
- [Node.js GitHub Pull Request #40478](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/40478)
- [Node.js GitHub Issue #40455](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40455)
- [Webpack.js.org config](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/commit/5a81c718d470cd4e82f177a5bd099164f4c6f7e9#diff-154021c8c1ce914c5be753b5667e4e615d0edfcb0874240c4fbf72a6424c7e65)