# Error when tried to install react_router_dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i tried to install react-router-dom

i got this error:

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
> at module.exports (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at handleParseError (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
> at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
> at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
> D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
> at module.exports (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
> at context.callback (D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
> at D:\Programming\pcbuildersite\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }

I already tried to update npm. That error appear when i tried to install `react-router-dom`

Edited:
Installed a clean react application, didn't help, reinstalled node, still the same error.

Comment: You should search for the error code, here is a post related to your error code: [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported?rq=2)

Comment: Try to add react-router-dom in a new react app. If that works, means there is something broken in this repo. Try deleting node_modules and package lock file and do once npm install