# how to fix the localhost problem if im using react on vscode?

Tags: reactjs, web, localhost

im running react on vscode and the local host is always refusing to connect, ive tried every possible solution, but this specifiv error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

it indicate issues related to cryptographic routines when the React app is trying to build or bundle using webpack.

sooo how can i fix this?

ive tried updating node but its the latest, i tried to clear cache using this: npm cache clean --force
i tired to reinstall dependancies : rm -rf node_modules and npm install
i tried to change the port, i tried to delete the .vscode file and recreate it, i tried running vscode and terminal as admin
and still nothing works

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported.

Comment: @codeing_monkey i couldnt fix it still, i tried all the possible solutions from that link :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.