# Why is my vercel keep making Webpack error when deploying?

Tags: webpack, next.js, hadoop-yarn, vercel

When i try to deploy a website in vercel that i edited and forked from another person's github repo it isn't working but it works on localhost with yarn run. can someone help me with this the error code shows as following. Its nextJs and react code BTW!

Failed to compile.
HookWebpackError: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at makeWebpackError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:45539:9)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:29467:12
at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140927:10), :105:1)
-- inner error --
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at getHashDigest (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-utils/index.js:1:29141)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-utils/index.js:1:31472
at String.replace ()
at Object.interpolateName (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-utils/index.js:1:31381)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/copy-file-plugin.js:41:51
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at getHashDigest (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-utils/index.js:1:29141)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-utils/index.js:1:31472
at String.replace ()
at Object.interpolateName (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-utils/index.js:1:31381)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/copy-file-plugin.js:41:51

> Build failed because of webpack errors
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

I tried to deploy on vercel and i was expecting it to work because it works perfectly fine on local host.

Comment: The error message looks similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported). Somehow the top-rated answer is not the accepted answer, though. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/4225384), most of the solutions are "hacks that leave your builds open to security threats".