# NodeJS - Unable to get latest react verion installed with mui version 5 on Node version 20.9.0

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui

Unable to get latest mui version with latest react on node 20.9.0

Steps I followed

1. npx create-react-app my-project
2. cd my-project
3. npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

No issues till here .. but then if I run this I get error

4. npm install @mui/base @mui/core @mui/icons-material @mui/styles

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/core@5.0.0-alpha.54
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/core
npm ERR!   @mui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/abcd/.npm/_logs/2024-03-16T17_22_45_664Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/abcd/.npm/_logs/2024-03-16T17_22_45_664Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution on the error.

`npm install` will fail when it encounters conflicting peerDependencies, here `@mui/core`

```
$ npm i @mui/base @mui/core @mui/icons-material @mui/styles --legacy-peer-deps
```

`--legacy-peer-deps`  ignore all peerDependencies while installing.

Comment: Thanks Yuvaraj. I am aware of the "--legacy-peer-deps" option. I have used it earlier when trying to run my project with older version of material UI. Package installation goes well but if I run the project with my code it runs into compilation erros and code fails. Is there a way where I dont have to use "--legacy-peer-deps" or "--force" options ?

Comment: Downgrade you react version to 17

Comment: Trying to port application on latest LTS node version. So currently not looking to downgrade. Version 17 also has issues such as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported