Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported on react 16 and node 21
year old react project, recently, I got this error when i try to run yarn start.
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at module.exports (.../node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at .../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at .../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at .../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
.../node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at module.exports (.../node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at .../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at .../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at .../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at .../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at .../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error',
    'error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported'
  ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Some post suggested to use: export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
Then i got this error, however, i am using react 16.8.0
src/index.tsx
  Line 11:1:  This should be done within a hook                                                                                            jest/require-hook
  Line 11:1:  ReactDOM.render is deprecated since React 18.0.0, use createRoot instead, see https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot  react/no-deprecated
  Line 26:1:  This should be done within a hook                                                                                            jest/require-hook

src/utils/axiosIntercepter.js
  Line 4:1:   This should be done within a hook  jest/require-hook
  Line 14:1:  This should be done within a hook  jest/require-hook

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Please try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

In the package.json file, update the 'start' and 'build' fields in the scripts part.
"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
"build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",


I've added node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider" into the .npmrc file, which I got from comment.

The error error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported occurs because of changes in how OpenSSL is handled in Node.js versions 17 and above. This issue typically arises when trying to run a project that uses Webpack or other tools that rely on cryptographic functions.
Solution 1: Downgrade Node.js to Version 16 or 14
If you can, downgrading to Node.js version 16 or 14 is the simplest and most reliable solution, as these versions don't have the OpenSSL changes that cause this issue.
To downgrade using nvm (Node Version Manager):
# Install nvm if you don't have it
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash

# Install Node.js version 14 (or 16)
nvm install 14

# Use Node.js version 14
nvm use 14

# Verify your Node.js version
node -v

After switching to Node.js 14, try running your project again:
npm start

Solution 2: Use the --openssl-legacy-provider Flag
If you want to stay on Node.js 17 or later, you can set an environment variable to use the legacy OpenSSL provider, which bypasses the issue:
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Or, you can modify the start script in your package.json to include this:
"scripts": {
  "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
  "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
  "test": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}

Please Notes:

The warnings about ReactDOM.render being deprecated are separate from the OpenSSL issue. These warnings indicate that your project is using React 16, which doesn't support createRoot (introduced in React 18). If you're using React 16, you can ignore these warnings for now, or consider upgrading to React 18+ to eliminate them.

The jest/require-hook warnings suggest that certain code should be moved inside a React hook. You may need to refactor your code if these are causing issues, but they're unrelated to the OpenSSL error.


These steps should resolve the issue. If you're still encountering problems, consider updating your dependencies or checking if your project can be upgraded to use React 18+ and the latest Webpack.

This answer should help others who encounter the same issue while also acknowledging the specific context of your project using React 16.
