Unable to start local host of Angular 7 website
I'm new to Angular and working on an old company project. It was made with Angular 7 and now I need to migrate it to 18. The problem is that as it is now, it won't even start. I ran npm install and npm start, but I just get these errors and I don't even know where to begin googling. Was hoping I could get some guidance on how to approach this
//npm install
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated protractor@5.4.2: We have news to share - Protractor is deprecated and will reach end-of-life by Summer 2023. To learn more and find out about other options please refer to this post on the Angular blog. Thank you for using and contributing to Protractor. https://goo.gle/state-of-e2e-in-angular

changed 68 packages, and audited 1123 packages in 26s

140 vulnerabilities (2 low, 46 moderate, 70 high, 22 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.


> gol-centz-app@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

(node:26680) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building 4/5 modules 1 active ...t\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:69
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:43:13)
    at processResource (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:280:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:427:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:635:10)
    at C:\Users\USER\Documents\Angular\GolCentz\GolCentz Clone\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:884:14 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.19.1

{
  "name": "gol-centz-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "admin-lte": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "devextreme": "19.1.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "^19.1.3",
    "devextreme-intl": "^19.1.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jszip": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}

At first I tried running npm audit fix --force as it suggested, but then that just lead to more errors, ones that I couldn't even find online, and I had to clone the source code again to redo everything because I didn't use version control the first time.

Does this answer your question? Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"

the error you're getting has nothing to do with your dependencies but with an wrong node version. you can find a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699772/2126544
angular v7 is quite an old version, so to get it up and running you should downgrade your node version from 18 to 8 or 10 (https://v7.angular.io/guide/quickstart#nodejs) first because there are probably APIs in use which are no longer supported in v18. if you don't already use one, I would recommend using an node version manager (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm or https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). with that you can easily switch between versions.
after that you should be able to start your application and then you can upgraded version by version. you will also have to change your node versions during this steps until you reach the latest version.

Delete json.lock file and node_modules directory and retry
As an addition: from 7 to 18 is a long way, if its a simple projekt, rewrite it in 18 new. Cause you have many new things and best practises.
